# Not able to attach gdb in OSX -unable to read unknown load command

Tags: c, xcode, macos, cocoa, gdb

I am using OSX 10.8.2 and gdb 6.3. I have to use both xcode 4.6.1 and xcode 3.

I have a simple c executable for which i am trying to attach gdb through command line. But i am not able to give break points. As soon as the gdb is attached i am getting the below lines.

```
unable to read unknown load command 0x2b
unable to read unknown load command 0x80000022
unable to read unknown load command 0x24
unable to read unknown load command 0x2a
```

I goggled it out and found that gdb 6.3 has few bugs for which above thing might be happening. so i thought of updating the gdb to 7.6. Even this is not happening.
Steps i did to install gdb 7.6

```
./congigure
make 
make install
```

make is ending with below lines

```
make[8]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-target'.
```

make install with below lines

```
make[11]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `install-target'.
```

I want gdb which is supported by xcode 3,4.6 as well as in command line. Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Install MacPorts and type `sudo port install gdb`.

Comment: @trojanfoe - I'm experiencing it under MacPorts GDB, too.

Answer (score 1):

They're just warnings, you're fine to ignore them.  The gdb binary you're using didn't include the definitions of these load commands (`LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY`, `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX`, etc see `/usr/include/mach-o/loader.h`) and it's complaining about them when it parses the Mach-O binaries with them included.  The gdb included in Xcode 4.6 will handle these without warning, fwiw.

Comment: No Actually i an not able to debug using breakpoints. I thought this is because of these warning

Comment: *"They're just warnings, you're fine to ignore them..."* - they are kind of hard to ignore when it results in a segfault on the debugger :) ***`unable to read unknown load command 0x24   unable to read unknown load command 0x24   unable to read unknown load command 0x29   Segmentation fault: 11`***.

Answer (score 0):

As I can figure out with make command output your program is compiled and not changed. So you have to `make clean` your code and try again. Make sure that you are compiling the code with `-g` parameter of gcc to link the symbol table of C to the executable, in order to give to gdb the necessary parameters for debugging. So, you must to have a look at makefile.